# Business logic in the API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture, business-logic

I have this method in my ClientsController:

```
//POST api/v1/clients
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateClient([FromBody] CreateClientDto createClientDto)
{
    await _createClientService.Create(createClientDto.MapToClient());
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetClient", new { clientId = createClientDto.ClientId });
}
```

As you can see, this method references a previously injected service.
The service looks like this:

```
public class CreateClientServiceImpl : ICreateClientService
{
    private readonly ConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext;

    public CreateClientServiceImpl(ConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext)
    {
        this.configurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
    }

    public async Task Create(Client client)
    {
        await configurationDbContext.Clients.AddAsync(client.ToEntity());
        await configurationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

This is where the problem arises. Where will I check if the clientId exists? I think not in the ICreateClientService because it would violate the Single Responsibility Principle rule. I can create next service which will check if the user exists and use it in controller method, but I think it will be too many logic in controller method. What should I do then? To be sure, ClientId is not an incremental Id, but too is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer this question: How do want your application to react, if a client already exists?

Also, are you aware of the fact that `SaveChangesAsync()` can throw a `DbUpdateException` or `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`? Currently, you are not handling these cases.

One possibility would be to introduce an exception, for example `DuplicateClientException` and throw this exception in your `CreateClientServiceImpl.Create` method, if this client already exists.
Another option is that `Create` returns a bool, indicating whether the create statement was successful. It could return false if it failed (one reason could be, that the client already exists).
You could also return a `Result`-object. There is a library by Ardelis, see [Result](https://github.com/ardalis/Result), which offers a solution to the problem you have.

Your controller method can then handle the exception, translate the method return value as you see fit or (automatically) turn the `Result` object into the correct status code, for example a `400 Bad Request`.

Right now, I believe your code would run into an exception, if you have your primary keys set up correctly, and your controller would return a `500 Internal Server Error`. If this is the behavior you want, then you don't have to change anything.

Comment: Thanks you! I was thinking SaveChangesAsync() would just stupidly sign a new client, even if value is unique and only save information about client duplicate in log file.